# Run DNS server on own ip

Tags: python, sockets, server, dns, localhost

I'm implementing a simple DNS server, which I want to run on my pc. But, as far as I understand the combination of my IP and port 53 (standard DNS server port) is already occupied.

This is how I tried to open socket:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('', 53))
```

This is an error message I get:

> socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

But, when I use `127.0.0.1` as IP address when creating a socket, everything works fine and I'm able to get requests.

This is what have tried so far (in Linux terminal I tried to kill the socket):

`fuser -k -n udp 53`

But it didn't work. So how can I run DNS server on my own IP address?

Comment: Your question is quite offtopic here, and I fear, except if it is only as a learning tool, that you are missing many pieces related to DNS, like for example the fact that it uses UDP **AND** TCP, not just UDP. To find currently opened sockets, you can also use `lsof` and `netstat`. Your own local recursive nameserver is probably already listening on some :53 sockets.

Comment: Yes, this is just for learning purpose